# django grappelli change_form.html override

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to extend django's admin change_form.html (django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html).

What makes this more complicated for me is that I've installed grappelli, which also extends it (grappelli/templates/admin/change_form.html)

Now, I want to change it in myproject (to apply for all apps/modules in my project), and have tried to place change_form in various places but to no avail:

- myproject/templates/admin/change_form.html
- myproject/templates/grappelli/change_form.html
- myproject/templates/admin/grappelli/change_form.html

Does anyone have a clue about where I should be placing my modified version of change_form.html in order for django to actually use it?

(any help on understanding django's search path & template extension mechanism will be appreciated).

Thanks!

Comment: May be your directory name is not correct. actual spell is `grappelli` not `grapelli` .

Comment: Thanks, Priyank!  But still, even after spelling "grappelli" correctly, it still didn't extend change_form.html for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include your template directory to `TEMPLATE_DIRS`

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/templates/'),
)
```

This way you can change the order in which Django reads your template files.