# Django: import-export && Grappelli

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli, django-import-export

I was using Django import-export app and now I want to add Grappelli in order to improve the Admin interface. I'm getting an error related to the templates. Any suggestion to get them work together?

Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/db_personal/personalinstituto/

Django Version: 1.7c1
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'import_export',
 'db_personal')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template C:\Gestion AI2\web_nueva\templates\admin\change_list.html, error at line 1
   maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
   1 :  {% extends "admin/change_list.html" %} 


   2 : 


   3 : {# Original template renders object-tools only when has_add_permission is True. #}


   4 : {# This hack allows sub templates to add to object-tools #}


   5 : {% block object-tools %}


   6 :   <ul class="object-tools">


   7 :     {% block object-tools-items %}


   8 :       {% if has_add_permission %}


   9 :         {{ block.super }}


   10 :       {% endif %}


   11 :     {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Here a solution: https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export/issues/38 But there's still a problem in how are showed the buttons Import, Export and Add because are hidden (are located between the word admin and Filter): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23171086/image.png

Comment: grappelli needs to be before import_export within INSTALLED_APPS. I have added an answer as well below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just gone through the same problem and here's a more step-by-step approach.

Create a directory in your project for the import_export templates and add a html file for the change_list_import template.

```
myproj
├── myproj
│   ├──url.py
│   ├──settings.py
├── manage.py
├── db_personal #myapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── models.py
|   ├── viewss.py
├── templates
|   ├── admin
|   |   ├── import_export
|   |   |   ├── change_list_import.html 
├── dashboard.py
```

Next, copy the following code in this template html file. Note that it needs to extend the grappelli changelist template, hence the reference to the location of this template:

```
{% extends "C:/Python27/lib/site-packages/grappelli/templates/admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
   <li><a href="import/" class="import_link">{% trans "Import" %}</a></li>
   {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid hardcoded path to the grappelli template?

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784134/django-grappelli-change-form-html-override) provides a way using TEMPLATE_DIRS which controls the order in which templates are loaded

Answer (score 1):

Well, i think your problem is not in the template script but the extend.
Your template tries to extend itself.

> templates\admin\change_list.html, error at line 1  1 :  {% extends
>   "admin/change_list.html" %}

admin/change_list.html refers to the basic django template change_list. It seems that your django-import-export change_list template has the same path. Your change_list template from django-import-export should be in 
*template/admin/**import_export**/change_list.html*

Comment: I've copied the change_list.html from import-export to C:\Gestion AI2\web_nueva\templates\admin\import_export/change_list.html but nothing changes. Should I change the extends as well?

Comment: @Alex_Loar Sorry it is not what i meant you to do. I am a bit confused. What app is this directory C:\Gestion AI2\web_nueva\templates\ from ? grappelli or import-export? Your error shows import-export change_list.html script. So I first thought the directory (...web_nueva\templates\) was import-export but now I am not sure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I use them together fine. I had to change this in admin/includes_grappelli/header.html :

```
-                    {% url admin:password_change as password_change_url %}
+                    {% url 'admin:password_change' as password_change_url %}

-                    {% url admin:logout as logout_url %}
+                    {% url 'admin:logout' as logout_url %}

-                {% url test-index as testindexurl %}
+                {% url 'test-index' as testindexurl %}

-                {% url django-admindocs-docroot as docsroot %}
+                {% url 'django-admindocs-docroot' as docsroot %}
```

And call it with ImportExportActionModelAdmin to avoid CSS problems.

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin

class MyModelAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    """
    Admin class for MyModel model
    """
    form = MyModelAdminForm

    list_display = ()
    ordering = []

    resource_class = MyModelResource
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I can't find the header.html :(

Comment: Should be in C:\Gestion AI2\web_nueva\templates\admin\includes_grappelli/
https://github.com/chronossc/django-grappelli/blob/master/grappelli/templates/admin/includes_grappelli/header.html

Comment: That's not in the latest version.

Comment: True ! Sorry, I was looking on internet without checking that. So it's my install which is built like this. I am continuing the dev after someone !

Comment: @Alex_Loar: well i add the same issue as you. The code sample from header.html is now in grappelli/templates/admin/base.html between line 90 and 100. But in my version, changes advised by HydrUra are already set. Check these and tell us what you find. https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/blob/f01d693f273ca91d77c6b149251f9ee5ff652652/grappelli/templates/admin/base.html

Comment: @jcs Exactly, in my version those changes are already set so problems still there

Answer (score 0):

> grappelli needs to be before import_export within INSTALLED_APPS.

Quoting from
https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/thirdparty.html